# ServiceStack: Custom login method and create manual IAuthSession for use with [Authenticate] attribute?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-auth

I'm trying to manually create an IAuthSession and saving it, so I can use the attribute [Authenticate] on my methods, but doesn't seem to work.

So, I have my `LoginHandler : Service` where I do some custom code to login a user, and then I do:

```c
namespace RequestHandlers
{
    public class LoginHandler : Service
    {
        public object Post(Login request)
        {
            // do magic login code
            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                IAuthSession session = GetSession();
                session.FirstName = "My First name"
                session.IsAuthenticated = true;
                base.Request.SaveSession(session); // save the session??
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(pc.GetFaultString());
            }
            return new LoginResponse() { Result = "OK" };
        }
    }
}
```

I was then my hope that the `base.Request.SaveSession(session);` would save the Session so that ServiceStack would later detect it and see that "aha, a protected method is allowed, since the user is logged in".

The response for the Login call is (in Fiddler):

```js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie: ss-id=TwOJExNFhBuVuDna1aDO;path=/;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=O4bJqgiLWRTFTOgcf2DD;path=/;expires=Mon, 08 Feb 2038 12:39:30 GMT;HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5,02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2018 12:39:31 GMT

f
{"Result":"OK"}
0
```

So, I get some cookie with a pid, I take that as the session id?

Now, I have the `Test` method that I after running the `Login` above, should be available, right? =)

```c
namespace tWorks.Alfa.Modules.ModuleRestApiService.Services.AlfaConnectService.Requests
{
    [Authenticate]
    [Route("/test")]
    public class Test : IReturn<TestResponse>
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But its not, I get a 401 error:

```C
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5,02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="/auth/basic"
Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2018 12:40:12 GMT

0
```

The call from Fiddler for `Test` is this:

```js
POST http://192.168.0.147:8080/alfaconnect/test HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.147:8080
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 18
DeviceUUID: 123asd123
Domain: AlfaOnline
Cookie: ss-id=TwOJExNFhBuVuDna1aDO
Cookie: ss-pid=O4bJqgiLWRTFTOgcf2DD

{"Message": "Hej"}
```

As you can see, I copied the ss-id and ss-pid from the Login response to the Test call.

What am I missing?

Here is my AppHost:

```c
    public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost(IModuleController moduleController, IContactModule contactModule) : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(Services.AlfaProService.AlfaProService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
              new IAuthProvider[] {
                new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
              }));

            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
        }

        public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
        {
            var routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
            if (requestType.FullName.Contains("AlfaConnectService"))
            {
                routes.Each(x => x.Path = "/alfaconnect" + x.Path);
            }
            else if (requestType.FullName.Contains("AlfaProService"))
            {
                routes.Each(x => x.Path = "/alfapro" + x.Path);
            }
            return routes;            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack also requires the `session.UserAuthName` to be set to the Username.

All ServiceStack's constructs are designed to work together, if you're not going to use ServiceStack's AuthProvider model just ignore it and implement your own Authentication. i.e. ignore all of ServiceStack's built-in Auth/Session features and use your own filters/validation instead.

Comment: Thanks again for input. So, I find the documentation on ServiceStack confusing or not clear, so, when you say "implement your own Authentication", what do you mean by that? That is what I tried to do above, wasnt it? =)

Comment: And with regards to my attempt above, am I close? Am I saving the session correctly in my `base.Request.SaveSession(session); ` ?

Comment: @Ted As in don't use any of ServiceStack's Authentication features, e.g. AuthFeature Plugin, `[Authenticate]` attribute, Session APIs, etc. They're all meant to work together.

Comment: So, that means I have to add my own authentication methods to each and every service method I have?

Comment: I thought a lot of what you have done with ServiceStack is to make it "pluggable" and for us to be able to use our own authenticate mechanisms. Since I cannot have one general login service (`/auth`) because I need to differentiate between logging into my AlfaPro service and the AlfaConnect service (all hosted on the same AppHost), I added my own login service at /alfapro/login and /alfaconnect/login and was hoping to create the IAuthSession manually, and then use [Authentiate]. I thought that was a neat usage =)

Comment: @Ted "Pluggable" means implementing and using your own Custom AuthProvider, it doesn't mean to completely bypass the Authentication process so that none of Authentication process can get executed. You can try manually saving the UserSession, but this is an unsupported configuration.

Comment: Alright, thanks for answers. Allow me to ask if this is a doable scenario, while still adhering to ServiceStack Authentication process =) 1) I have several "sub-services", `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` and I have made an override on the GetRouteAttributes in AppHost so that all service-methods in `ServiceA` gets a route prefix `/servicea` and `/serviceb` for the other one. Now, to login "properly", I have to use the same `/auth` for both. So, I cannot really determine what service they are logging into inless I add it in the headers for the login, right?

Comment: @Ted There's only 1 UserSession, if they're Authenticated they're Authenticated everywhere. You can add additional Authorization restrictions like an additional Role/Permission or custom property on your Custom UserSession and then use `[RequiredRole]` or your own Request Filter attribute to provide additional validation. Have you considered having 2 separate AppHost instances? If these multiple "sub services" require separate Authentication, may be less fragile and complex hosting in 2 separate ServiceStack instances.

Comment: Yeah, I have considered, and its an option - today we have different modules on different ports, but I wanted to get away from opening up many different ports (too messy, routers, firewalls etc), so to have one port for all services. Yeah, I saw the roles/permissions, I'll try to work around this, probably with additional  http headers when going to /auth ... or something.

Comment: @Ted You could use a Reverse Proxy to simplify this where it can transparently proxy to different instances running on the same server.

Comment: Sorry, I tried using the `/auth/credentials` all the way, with a custom  `CredentialsAuthProvider`. The `TryAuthenticate` is fired, the `OnAuthenticated` is fired and I do the `return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);` there. I get a `SessionId":"briU1JfuYkjbza9D9Gyb` from the `/auth`, but then when I try to use that session id in the next requset, I get a 401...

Comment: @Ted What do you mean try to use? You shouldn't be manually using it, the ss-id/ss-pid Session Ids are added as a Cookie and the browser/HTTP Client should be automatically be resending it on subsequent requests. Try testing this on a browser first with `/auth/credentials?Username=xxx&Password=xxx` then in the same browser, try to access your Service.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. The thing is, I need to use this stuff in apps, not using a web browser, so I need to understand how to build the subsequent requests so that they will be allowed. I tried to do this in Fiddler, but I didnt get it to work.

Comment: @Ted All HTTP Clients should resend cookies and you can Authenticate in all ServiceStack ServiceClients (in all supported languages) by [sending a populated Authenticate Request DTO](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#sending-authenticate-request-dto).

Comment: Alright, thx for info. I figured out how to send the POST anyways, its like this: `Cookie: ss-opt=temp; ss-id=woH9ET5NqO4sIPjHSBCL; ss-pid=VklKJpWrOyPLIhBYhyw1; X-UAId=12717711`